# Performance Impact of __attribute__((packed)), is performance impact present ONLY for instructions involving "packed" structs?

Tags: c++, performance

This is an extension to the question : [Can __attribute__((packed)) affect the performance of a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454673/can-attribute-packed-affect-the-performance-of-a-program) (In this question answers seems to give a general answer on performance)

**My Case :**
I intend to use "**attribute**((packed))" use C(C++)-structs on rarely executed code.

My question is, is aforementioned(in above Answered question) Performance degradation present ONLY for instructions involving "packed" structs ? or is it present for code that does NOT use "packed" structs too ?

e.g.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) Abc {int y = 0;...};

void rarelyCalledFunction() { uses above Abc struct. Abc is NOT used in any other function }

//other functions exists F1, F2, F3, ... etc
```

Say "rarelyCalledFunction" is called only on **start-up and only once** per every 4 hrs (assume program runs for 24 hrs). Does performance of functions F1, F2, F3 etc degrade too ?

Comment: I would say only functions using your packed structure is impacted.

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason to assume that unrelated code would be affected by the existence of some packed structure elsewhere.

Comment: Measure it and see.